# How can I get this click to continually happen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want is for the '.child' image to always be on the screen, but the .parent div to show and hide. I've been able to get it to show once and hide once, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to recur.

```js
var main = function() {

  $('#logo').on('click',function() {
    $(this).parent('.parent').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#logo').on('click',function() {
      $(this).parent('.parent').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
  });


};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.parent {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.child {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='jumbotron'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <img id='logo' class='child' src="http://content.sportslogos.net/logos/6/216/full/813.gif" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, if you hide `.parent` then it's going to hide it's children as well, as in it will hide `.child`. If you want to hide `.parent` and show `.child` you'll have to move `.child` out of `.parent`.

Comment: On top of that, your click event is bound every time you click on logo, instead of once.  Move your second click handler out of the first one.

Comment: Use toggle to trigger the hide and show effect you want. On click it will switch to visible or hidden depending on its previous state. Also don't use delegated events if it's not necessary. Use click instead of on

Comment: @LelioFaieta .on isn't just for delegated events.. the op's events aren't delegated.

Comment: @LelioFaieta He's not using delegated events. There's no `selector` argument to `.on()`, so it's an ordinary binding.

Comment: @MikeC That doesn't seem to be the case for `visibility`, only `display`. The logo stays visible even when the parent is hidden.

Comment: and will .toggle correctly set the display back to "flex" instead of block? (maybe it will, i dunno)

Comment: @KevinB He's not toggling `.jumbotron`, so I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: sorry, I was referring to *"Use toggle to trigger the hide and show effect you want."*, which would be toggling `.parent`, which is `display: flex`

Comment: What's the difference with $('#logo').click if The objects are in the Dom when it is loaded @Barmar

Comment: @MikeC actually that's not true with `visibility`. A child can be visible even when parent is `hidden`

Comment: There's no difference. `$("#logo").click()` calls `$("#logo").on("click")` internally.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice it was using `visibility`.

Comment: @Daedalus      When I move it out it doesn't do anything at all

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Barmar I've learned something new! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had tried this earlier but must have made a mistake in my code.

Added class .active and was able to use .toggleClass('active');

```js
var main = function() {

  $('#logo').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.parent').toggleClass('active');

  });


};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.parent {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.active {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.child {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='jumbotron'>
  <div class='active parent'>
    <img id='logo' class='child' src="http://content.sportslogos.net/logos/6/216/full/813.gif" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single handler that toggles the visibility of the DIV.

```js
var main = function() {

  $('#logo').on('click',function() {
    $(this).parent(".parent").css("visibility", function(i, oldvis) {
        return oldvis == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
    });
  });

};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.parent {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.child {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='jumbotron'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <img id='logo' class='child' src="http://content.sportslogos.net/logos/6/216/full/813.gif" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do the toggle:

```
var main = function() {

  var visible = false;

  $('#logo').on('click',function() {

    visible = !visible;

    var val = (visible) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    $(this).parent('.parent').css('visibility', val);


  });

};
```